# python mysql date error "raise errorclass, errorvalue"

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to fetch records from mysql database between two dates using python-mysql but facing raise errorclass, errorvalue

below is my code and please let me know where I am doing wrong

```
request_date = parse(from_date) #2018-06-01 00:00:00
parsed_from_date = request_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")

request_date1 = parse(to_date) #2018-06-04 00:00:00
parsed_to_date = request_date1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
query_string = 'SELECT * FROM test_inof where test_image = %s and  test_readydate_time>=%s and test_readydate_time<=%s'
if(area):
    query_string = query_string + " and area = ' " +  area +  " ' "
if(team):
    query_string = query_string + " and team =' " + team + " ' " 
t = testInfo.objects.raw(query_string,[image,str(parsed_from_date), str(parsed_to_date)])
```

Error is:

```
File "c:\users\dasarr\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-flprbl\MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test_inof where image = 'test' and  test_readydate_time>' at line 1")
```

Comment: You don't need to use `'` around your `area` and `team`.

Comment: @Frank AK: I have removed area and team from my query, still facing same issue, I think the issue is with dates

Comment: Had your tried your `SQL` directly?

Comment: Don't fill parameters into SQL using string operations. [Bad things will happen](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Wait ... `testInfo.objects.raw` ... is this a django model? If so, please also show us the `testInfo` model class.

Comment: Resolved it , here is the code  query_string = 'SELECT * FROM test_inof where test_image = %s and  test_readydate_time>=%s and test_readydate_time<=%s'          t = testInfo.objects.raw(query_string,[image],[str(parsed_from_date)], [str(parsed_to_date)]])